# Ruby Concept - Yield

Tags: ruby

Working my way through Ruby concepts right now. Coming from a VB background, there are some concepts I don't quite grasp yet. Yield is one of them. I understand how it works in a practical sense, but fail to see the significance of Yield, or when and how I would use it to its full potential.

Answer (score 4):

Yield is part of a larger system of *closures* in Ruby. It is a very powerful part of the language and you will find it in every Ruby script you encounter.

http://www.robertsosinski.com/2008/12/21/understanding-ruby-blocks-procs-and-lambdas/

Comment: Saving this for tomorrow morning, after my first caffeine shot!  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's good to have an understanding of how yield works but I seldom use it and thought that the same was true for others. The comments to this answer could indicate otherwise.

Ruby's yield statement hands over the control to a block given to the method. After the block has finished the control is returned to the method and it keeps on executing the statement directly after the yield.

Here's a variant of the overused Fibonacci sequence

```
def fib(upto) 
  curr,  succ = 1, 1 
  while curr <= upto
      puts "before"
      yield curr
      puts "after"
      curr, succ = succ, curr+succ 
  end 
end
```

You then call the method with something like

```
fib(8) {|res| puts res}
```

and the output will be

```
before
1
after
before
1
after
before
2
after
before
3
after
before
5
after
before
8
after
```

Comment: "in practice you will almost never use it" - That strongly depends on what you do. We have quite a few places in our production app where we make use of `yield`.

Comment: I use code that uses yield quite often but I seldom write any yields myself. Guess I was way too subjective there.

Comment: @JonasElfström Some examples: dependency injection. DSLs. The `yield self` pattern for something like the block configuration form in gemspecs.

Comment: @MichaelKohl You are clearly a very advanced Ruby programmer. As for DI I'm with Jamis Buck on that one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/283466/ruby-dependency-injection-libraries/283600#283600 http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2008/11/9/legos-play-doh-and-programming and I also guess that's it's quite uncommon among Ruby programmers to write gems or even DSLs.
I'm not picking a fight here.

Comment: @JonasElfström: Didn't think you were and thanks for the links :-) I agree on the DI front btw, as said, that was a list of examples.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your input.  This was a nice easy example of the workings of yield, thanks :-)

Comment: @user973718 If it helped you then please check it as an accepted answer or upvote it and check another answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Good reading: http://blog.codahale.com/2005/11/24/a-ruby-howto-writing-a-method-that-uses-code-blocks/

Comment: Thanks for the link: good reading for a beginner like me!